# Missing OAuth request token cookie error using tornado and TwitterMixin

Tags: python, cookies, twitter, oauth, tornado

I'm using tornado and the TwitterMixin and I use the following basic code:

```
class OauthTwitterHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.TwitterMixin): 
    @tornado.web.asynchronous 
    def get(self): 
        if self.get_argument("oauth_token", None): 
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth)) 
            return 
        self.authorize_redirect() 
    def _on_auth(self, user): 
        if not user: 
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Twitter auth failed") 
        self.write(user) 
        self.finish()
```

For me it works very well but sometimes, users of my application get a 500 error which says:
 Missing OAuth request token cookie

I don't know if it comes from the browser or the twitter api callback configuration.
I've looked through the tornado code and I don't understand why this error 
appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !!

It was due to my DNS.

I didn't put the redirection for www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com so sometimes the cookie was set in www. and sometimes not then my server didn't check in the good place, didn't find the cookie and then send me a 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons why this might happen:

1. Some users may have cookies turned off, in which case this won't work.
2. The cookie hasn't authenticated. It's possible that the `oauth_token` argument is set, but the cookie is not. Not sure why this would happen, you'd have to log some logging to understand why.

At any rate, this isn't an "error," but rather a sign the user isn't authenticated. Maybe if you see that you should just redirect them to the authorize URL and let them try again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening to me is that the Callback URL configuration was pointing to a different domain.

Take a look at the settings tab for your application at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ or if the users getting the error are accessing your site from a different domain.

See: http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/55aa42eef42fa1ac