# OAuth twitter tornado python

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to integrate a twitter login on my app, I wrote this code

```
class AuthTwitterHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.TwitterMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        print 'GET'
        if self.get_argument("oauth_token", None):
            print 'GET OK'
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
            return
        print 'REDIRECT'
        self.authenticate_redirect()

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def _on_auth(self, user):
        print 'ONAUTH'
        if not user:
            print 'Broken'
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Twitter auth failed")
            # Save the user using, e.g., set_secure_cookie()
        print 'not Broken'
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
```

and as callback_url in my twitter app I put the same address of this handler, my output is:

```
GET
REDIRECT
GET
GET OK
ONAUTH
Broken
```

and my log said:

```
2012-06-18 16:56:09,650 - root - INFO - Logging started
2012-06-18 16:56:09,821 - root - INFO - Server starting on port 443
2012-06-18 16:56:16,170 - root - INFO - 304 GET /auth (127.0.0.1) 0.72ms
2012-06-18 16:56:19,215 - root - INFO - 302 POST /auth (127.0.0.1) 1.35ms
2012-06-18 16:56:19,719 - root - INFO - 302 GET /auth/twitter (127.0.0.1) 429.17ms
2012-06-18 16:56:20,464 - root - WARNING - Missing OAuth request token cookie
2012-06-18 16:56:20,465 - root - WARNING - 500 GET /auth/twitter?oauth_token=Nbed9YQseoNC3YjdFkbOPS5An7OhfewcEgp3oPuq4&oauth_verifier=uGWWoItQ7SXa1Bt8lSDs1N8iVXvBFIcKtCEpZ1mmI4 (127.0.0.1): Twitter auth failed
2012-06-18 16:56:20,465 - root - ERROR - 500 GET /auth/twitter?oauth_token=Nbed9YQseoNC3YjdFkbOPS5An7OhfewcEgp3oPuq4&oauth_verifier=uGWWoItQ7SXa1Bt8lSDs1N8iVXvBFIcKtCEpZ1mmI4 (127.0.0.1) 12.96ms
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dupe of "[Missing OAuth request token cookie error using tornado and TwitterMixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774563/missing-oauth-request-token-cookie-error-using-tornado-and-twittermixin)", so three questions:

1. What is the fully qualified domain name of your website?
2. If you use a web browser plugin like HTTPFox, or use Wireshark, what is the exact cookie that you get back? More precisely what domain is the cookie associated with?
3. What is the full URL of your Twitter app's callback URL?

This isn't an error with Tornado; I've used the [exact same code](https://github.com/asimihsan/listpile/blob/master/authauth/src/authauth_view_auth_request_handlers.py) with success.  So it's worth focusing on your Twitter app's settings, where your site is hosted, and the exact cookie you're getting back.

Comment: my website is http://restfs.beolink.org as application website i put the same, as callback I put https://127.0.0.1/auth/twitter

Comment: And what happens when you use http://restfs.beolink.org/auth/twitter as your callback URI? Maybe read this article: http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2009/08/17/how-to-quickly-set-up-a-test-for-twitter-oauth-authentication-from-your-local-machine/